# Print Label by using Bluetooth Label printer and Delphi 11 FMX

Tags: bluetooth, firemonkey, thermal-printer, delphi-11-alexandria

We are developing a mobile app written by Delphi 11 FMX, from which we need to print small label to a Bluetooth label printer.

we tested in android phone, the Bluetooth connection is successful, but when we try to send printing command (ESC/POS) to the printer, we can see the printer responded(with beep, and 'waiting for data' is shown on the small screen), then the printer moves the label to the next one, but it doesn't print anything, just blank.

First we thought there are something wrong with the printer, then we downloaded 2 different label printing apps from Google play, both are working, and printed text successfully.

Here is the source code:

```
const
 UUID = '{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}';
Var
 FSocket: TBluetoothSocket ;

//connect Bluetooth printer 
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);  
function ConnectPrinter(pDeviceName: String): boolean;
var
   lDevice: TBluetoothDevice;
begin
  Result := False;
  lDevice := GetDeviceByName(pDeviceName);
  if lDevice <> nil then
    begin
       FSocket := lDevice.CreateClientSocket(StringToGUID(UUID), False);
    if FSocket <> nil then
   begin
      FSocket.Connect;
     Result := FSocket.Connected
   end;
end;
end;

begin
if  (printerName.Text <> '') then
begin
 if ConnectPrinter(printerName.Text) then
begin
  Label1.Text := 'Connected';
end
else
begin
  Label1.Text := 'Disconnected';
end;
end
else
begin
 ShowMessage('No device name provided');
end;
end;

// print text to Bluetooth Printer
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (FSocket <> nil) and (FSocket.Connected) then
begin 
FSocket.SendData(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chr(27) + chr(64)));  //initial printer
//the printer responds with beep, and 'waiting for data' shown on the small screen`
FSocket.SendData(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chr(27) + chr(97) + chr(0)));     //Left aligned
FSocket.SendData(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chr(27) + chr(33) + chr(0)));      //Character parameter set
FSocket.SendData(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chr(29) + chr(33) + chr(0)));      //default font size 
FSocket.SendData(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('Print via Bluetooth ')); // send text to printer
FSocket.SendData(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chr(27) + chr(100) + chr(1))); // Print and feed paper 1 line
// the printer feeds the paper by 1 line, but nothing printed on the label
end;
end;
```

[image]